# How would I implement an ID to identify classes?

Tags: python-3.x, oop

I'm making a text-based game and want for each enemy type to have an ID, and every enemy to be put in a room with an ID, like `enemy = Enemy(123)`. I don't know how to begin doing this.

definitions.py :

```
class Enemy:
    def __init__(self, cid):
        self.name = ???
        self.hp = ???   # Here is my problem! How do I get the classes
                        # from the ID?
        self.ap = ???
    def __del__(self):
        print(self.name,"died.")
    def attack(self, target):
        target.hp -= self.ap
        if (target.hp > 0):
            pass
        elif (target.hp <= 0):
            del target
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name, hp, ap):
        self.name = name
        self.hp = hp
        self.ap = ap
    def __del__(self):
        print(self.name,"died.")
    def attack(self, target)
        target.hp -= self.ap
        if (target.hp > 0):
            pass
        elif (target.hp <= 0):
            del target
class Item:
    def __init__(self, iid):
        self.name = iid.name
        self.desc = iid.desc
        self.value = iid.value
    def __del__(self):
        print("debug: ITEM DESTROYED")
```

enemies.py:

```
import "definitions.py"

class Placeholder(Enemy):
    name = "PLACEHOLDER"
    hp = 1
    ap = 1
    cid = 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is cache all the instances of the class when it is being created in a static dict variable by IDs, that way you can get the instance in `O(1)`. Below is an example:

```
class Enemy:

    __REFS__ = {}

    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
        Enemy.__REFS__[id] = self

    @staticmethod
    def get_instance(id):
        return Enemy.__REFS__.get(id)
```

Now suppose you have to get an Enemy or player by ID, simply call `Enemy.get_instance(id)` with the correct ID.